# Extract and print all links (not to download the contents) from an archived website

Tags: shell-script

I want to extract and print all links (not to download the contents) from an archived website i.e. `www.foosite.com/archive`
traversing all folders and subfolders.

scenario:
I'm at a web archive like this
`www.foosite.com/archive` 
that has directories and subdirectories with downloadable files like

`-man.pdf
-.listing.txt
|-Books/
    |-my_book.pdf
    |-new_books.pdf
    |-Classics/ 
|-Songs
   |-annie's.song.mp3
   |-summer.of.69.mp3
-robot.txt
................`

I'm going to (recursively)traverse all the directories and get all the (downloadable) file paths (urls) like

`https://www.asite.com/man.pdf
https://www.asite.com/read.txt
https://www.asite.com/Books/my_book.pdf
https://www.asite.com/Books/new_books.pdf
https://www.asite.com/Classics/.....
https://www.asite.com/Classics/........
https://www.asite.com/Songs/annie's.song.mp3
.......
https://www.asite.com/terms.txt
............................`

But my shell script, where I tried to simulate simple web browsing technique with `lynx`, the output gets stuck in an infinite recursion (think the problem is more syntactic than implementation).

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

links=`/usr/bin/lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers $1`

function dump_primary_links() {

        for link in $links 
        do
            echo "$link" | grep -P "\/$" > /dev/null
            # if link ends with "/" that's a directory 

            if [  $? -eq 0  ]; then
                echo "primary link:$link"
                print_directory_items $link
                 # now recursively traverse the directory 
            else
                echo "$link" # else a normal link

            fi

        done


    }



function print_directory_items() {
    # get contents of directory 
    lst=`/usr/bin/lynx -dump -listonly -nonumbers $link`


     for lnk in $lst 
        do
            echo "$lnk" | grep -P "\/$" > /dev/null 
            # if there is a directory in $lst then travel directory recursively 

            if [  $? -eq 0  ]; then

                link=$lnk
                print_directory_items $link
            else
                echo "$lnk" # directory contents
            fi
       done

    }


get_link
```

**NB:** I know python (requests and Beautifulsoup or Scrapy) would be nice solution in this case, But I just want a simple unix simulation
of browsing or "web directory traversal"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mirror a website using `wget`, but you can also tell it to act as a web-spider so it will not download anything.

So you can do that but make sure to save the log:

```
wget --no-directories --mirror --spider "$url" 2>&1 | tee "$log"
```

In my case, in the log I found something like this:

```
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2017-12-19 07:19:23--  URL
```

Then I used `grep` to retrieve the URLs:

```
grep -P -o -e '(?<=^--....-..-.. ..:..:..--  )(.*)' "$log"
```

Example:

```
$ wget --no-directories --mirror --spider https://utw.me/file/scripts/ 2>&1 | tee log.txt
...
$ grep -P -o -e '(?<=^--....-..-.. ..:..:..--  )(.*)' log.txt
...
https://utw.me/file/scripts/Fate%20Zero/%5BUTW%5D%20Fate%20Zero%20-%2001.ass
https://utw.me/file/scripts/Fate%20Zero/%5BUTW%5D%20Fate%20Zero%20-%2002.ass
https://utw.me/file/scripts/Fate%20Zero/%5BUTW%5D%20Fate%20Zero%20-%2003.ass
https://utw.me/file/scripts/Fate%20Zero/%5BUTW%5D%20Fate%20Zero%20-%2004.ass
https://utw.me/file/scripts/Fate%20Zero/%5BUTW%5D%20Fate%20Zero%20-%2005.ass
...
```

Comment: @faquir It could be rewritten as `(?<=^--\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}--   )(.*)`

Comment: +1 for poetic transformation. in fact my hack is `grep -P  '(http|https)(.*expected_format$)' log.txt | awk '{print $3}'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you fell a loop searching for https://www.asite.com/Books/ (from https://www.asite.com/) and https://www.asite.com/ (from one of it's subdir).

`wget`, `curl` and `lynx` have options to go down/fetch items on many conditions (don't go leave initial site, max depth is X, use ftp, and so on).

on a side note:

- you didn't show full code.
- you call `print_directory_items` with an argument, but don't catch it (it would be localy know as `$1` )
- prefer `$( )` over backquote

Comment: this is the full script I've written.

Comment: +1 for informative answer and code analysis. 
In fact I didn't know the tools had those options.  :)